# Surjectivity of the pullback

Tags: differential-geometry

I've tried to prove the naturality of the pullback of a connection. I've reduced it to the following question:

*Is the pullback a surjective mapping on the space of sections of a vector bundle?*
i.e., suppose I have a smooth vector bundle $~E\to M$, and a smooth map $~f:N\to M$. Then is
$$f^*:\Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(f^*E)$$
surjective, where $f^*E$ is the pullback bundle over $N$?

It seems intuitive, but I'm struggling to prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally no. For example, if $M$ is a one-point space and $E=\mathbb R^n\to M$ is the trivial rank-$n$ vector bundle over $M$, then $f^*E$ is the trivial bundle $N\times \mathbb R^n\to N$.  In this case, $\Gamma(E)$ is finite-dimensional (just a copy of $\mathbb R^n$), while $\Gamma(f^*E)$ is infinite-dimensional (essentially the set of all smooth functions from $N$ to $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: Haha I'm a fan of your books on manifolds. Kinda wish there was a section on pullback bundles in one of them :)

Comment: @David, thank you. I might someday write a book about bundles (I have a few draft chapters hanging around somewhere), which will definitely contain a section on pullback bundles. But don't hold your breath.